# Magento + RequireJS - How to use non-AMD custom javascript with jQuery?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs

First off, I made a custom javascript file, `main.js`. Quite simple; it's just this:

```
$("#testp").text("Hello!");
```

`#testp` is in one of my phtml files, with just `<p id="testp">Hello World!</p>`.

Beforehand, just to let you know: jQuery is imported automatically by RequireJS because `jquery.js` is under the baseURL already. In the Chrome Firebug console, I can confirm this by typing `jQuery` and an object is sent back. However, the commonly used `$` which I need to access jQuery is **undefined**. This is a problem because I have plenty of other libraries that use `$` in place of `jQuery` keyword.

My questions are:

1. How would I **import** main.js into RequireJS so that the script can be executed? If main.js runs successfully, I would expect the paragraph to show "Hello!" instead of "Hello World!"
2. Main.js is dependent on jQuery. How would I make sure that jQuery will be **accessible** in main.js?
3. The `jQuery` keyword returns an object while `$` does not. How can I **configure** jQuery to let $ be a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

Require forces us to avoid global variables, if you want to use $ in your script you have to define it as a AMD module

```
define([
    "jquery"
], function ($) {

    // Here you can use $ with a local scope

});
```

Then declare your script in require-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Yourmodule':'path/to/main',
        }
};
```